# Where's the syntax error in this program?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This program I created in python is supposed to count the number of uppercase letters, lower case, digits, and number of white space characters in a text file.  It keeps coming back with syntax error. I'm having trouble finding out why my error is.

```
infile = open("text.txt", "r")

uppercasecount, lowercasecount, digitcount = (0, 0, 0)

for character in infile.readlines():

    if character.isupper() == True:
        uppercasecount += 1

   if character.islower() == True:
        lowercasecount += 1

   if character.isdigit() == True:
        digitcount += 1

print(uppercasecount),(lowercasecount),(digitcount)

print "Total count is %d Upper case, %d Lower case and %d Digit(s)" %(uppercasecount, lowercasecount, digitcount)
```

Comment: change `print(uppercasecount),(lowercasecount),(digitcount)` to `print(uppercasecount,lowercasecount,digitcount)`.Also `readlines` gives you a list. try `.read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
print(uppercasecount),(lowercasecount),(digitcount)
```

to:

```
print uppercasecount,lowercasecount,digitcount
```

Instead of `readlines`, use `read`:

```
for character in infile.read():
```

`readlines` will read the whole file as a list of line

`read` will read the whole file as a string

Comment: Thank you so much. If it's not too much to ask Do you know how I would be able to add the number of white space characters in the file as well

Comment: you want to count the number the white space too??

Comment: use `str.isspace` for whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Complete answer for python `2` and `3`. Try this if you want to get count of `letters` not `words`

```
infile = open("text.txt", "r")

uppercasecount, lowercasecount, digitcount = (0, 0, 0)

for character in infile.read():

    if character.isupper() == True:
        uppercasecount += 1

    if character.islower() == True:
        lowercasecount += 1

    if character.isdigit() == True:
        digitcount += 1

print(uppercasecount,lowercasecount,digitcount)

print("Total count is %d Upper case, %d Lower case and %d Digit(s)" %(uppercasecount, lowercasecount, digitcount))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If it's not too much to ask Do you know how I would be able to add the number of white space characters in the file as well.

Comment: Use Counter ,   https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter